Any etymological relation between なる and なり?
I'm wondering if there's any etymological relation between the modern verb なる (also 成る, 為る), meaning "to become, to be completed", and the classical auxiliary verb なり (also 也), a copula with a meaning similar to modern だ. The latter is almost surely from にあり, or に + あり (also 有り), while the first is seemingly related to なす (also 成す, 為す) and to 形. However, I can't find anything that says the two (なる/成る/為る and なり) are related. Could なる be from に + ある, using the attributive form of classical 有り instead of the terminal? If not, is there another etymology known for なる? Or is it simply a mystery?

Unfortunately the verb なる is attested from the oldest documents, so nothing is surely known. But generally speaking, difference in Old Japanese conjugation types suggests they are not likely to share the same origin.

Also syntax of their usage is different. naru "to become" uses ni when used with nouns, while nari/naru copula is used directly. Examples: "ware pitə ni ari" = "ware pitə nari" = "I am human"; "ware pitə ni naru" = "I (will) become human"; "pitə ni aru ware" = "pitə naru ware" = "I, who am human"; "pitə ni naru ware" = "I, who (will) become human". If naru "to become" was contraction of ni aru, then ni naru would have to come from ni ni aru, which looks very unlikely.

Thank you both for the information! That makes a lot of sense. Wiktionary also tells me that なる is likely to be related to the hypothesized Proto-Japonic copula *nu, which I've also seen as the source of に (along with auxiliary verb ぬ and genitive particle の).
